# Polytropic process

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

In the polytropic process : $PV^X =$const.

How is it possible that this equation is correct despite that $T$ is constant at $X=1$ only?

Is it not true that $PV=NRT=$const. only when $T$ is constant?
for example, if $X=0$, then $P$ is constant but $T$ is not.
Please aware me if the question is not clear enough.

Comment: In a polytropic process, the temperature is changing (unless x = 1), right?

Comment: from what i was taught, yes.

Comment: Then can't the temperature being constant be a special case of a polytropic process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X=0$ it is an isobaric (constant pressure) process. If $X=1$ it is an isothermal (constant temperature) process.

The equation for a polytropic process is generally written as

$$pV^{n}=C$$

Where $n$ is called the polytropic index (not to be confused with $n$ being the number of moles of a gas) and $C$ is a constant. The equation can be used to describe various different expansion and compression processes depending on the value of the polytropic index. Examples are

$n=0$ for an isobaric (constant pressure) process

$n=$ + infinity for an isochoric (constant volume) process

$n=1$ for an ideal gas isothermal (constant temperature) process

$n=\gamma = \frac{C_P}{C_V}$ for an ideal gas isentropic (reversible adiabatic) process

For an ideal gas, closed system (no change in mass), the ideal gas equation applies to all processes

$$pV=nRT$$

Where $n$ is the number of moles of gas, and $R$ the universal gas constant.

For an isothermal (constant temperature) process, $nRT$ = constant, or

$$pV=C$$

This is a polytropic process where $n=1$, as indicated above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing between [ideal gas law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law) and polytropic processes.

Polytropic is a general process and it is defined as a process where $PV^x = const$ (This constant may not equal to $nRT$). You are mistakenly assuming $ PV^x = nRT$ **for all $x$** which is wrong.

For example,  if $x=2$ then
$PV^2 \ne nRT$ . It will be some other constant but definitely not equal to $nRT$